# Comparison with HTML tags

Tags: java, string, equality

I am wondering why the 2nd if statement is not being evaluated to true...

```
 while ((tmp = yearReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(tmp.length() >= 22){
            System.out.println(tmp.substring(0, 12));
            if(tmp.substring(0, 12) == "<li><a href="){
                System.out.println("This should print...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Prints this...

```
 <li><a href=
 <li><a href=
 <li><a href=
```

Comment: Short answer: use `equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't compare `String` objects with `==` operator.

In Java, `==` operator compare instances for objects. In your case, they're obviously not equal. So, change your `==` for `equals()` instead:

```
if("<li><a href=".equals(tmp.substring(0, 12)))
```

but be aware that `equals()` can't be invoked on `null` references, as it will throw a `NullPointerException`. You must check if instance is not `null` before invoking it.